# scalac: Token not found: /Users/mpa/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/compile-server/tokens/54149

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scala-3

What means this exception and how can I fix it?

```
scalac: Token not found: /Users/mpa/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/compile-server/tokens/54149
```

I have a **Scala 3** project in **IntelliJ 2021.3**:

[image: Project Config]

It seamed to appear randomly when building the project with IntelliJ.

I tried:

- `sbt clean` / `sbt compile` and `sbt reload`.
- close IntelliJ / delete `.idea` folder and open Project newly.

Using `sbt` works just fine. So adjusting the config like this works, but I want to use the build from IntelliJ:

[image: Project Config sbt]

Comment: Scala 3 support is still being developed by JetBrains. They are recommending to use nightly builds of Scala plugin to have the latest fixes. You might want to try EAP version of Idea also

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same issue with scala 2.13. `File -> Invalidate Caches...` option in Intellij fxed the issue for me

Comment: just restarting the IDE fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Just Restarting intellij, fixes it. as commented by @parse